# CUDA thread indexing returning unexpected results for very simple kernel VS 2015 update 3

Tags: cuda

I was writing my first kernel and set a simple program to assign the thread index to that location in an array, it works for the first 1/4 of the array, ie it stops at 25 for size 100 and 12 for size 50. Then the rest are zeroes. I tested to make sure blockdim was coming out correctly and it was, this program is so simple and follows examples so closely I don't know what could be wrong with it.

Is the computer grouping my thread into four blocks or something?

```
__global__ void index_initialize(int* data)
{
    // set data at index to index
    data[threadIdx.x] = threadIdx.x;
}

void zero_initialize(int* data, int size)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        data[i] = 0;
    }
}

void print_array(int* data, int size)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        std::cout << data[i] << " ";

        if (i % 20 == 0 && i > 0) std::cout << '\n';
    }
}


int main()
{
    GpuTimer timer;

    // size
    int size = 100;

    // host array
    int* host = new int[size];

    // device array
    int* device = new int[size];

    // zero out device and host
    zero_initialize(host, size);
    zero_initialize(device, size);

    // allocate size ints on device
    cudaMalloc(&device, size * sizeof(int));

    // call kernel on one thread block of size
    index_initialize<<<1, size>>> (device);

    // synchronize
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();

    // copy device to host
    cudaMemcpy(host, device, size, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

    // reset device
    cudaDeviceReset();

    // print out host
    print_array(host, size);

    // free memory
    cudaFree(device);

}
```

this program is doing the same thing, it stops at 25

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>

#include "cs344\Lesson Code Snippets\Lesson 2 Code Snippets\gputimer.h"

#include "cuda_runtime.h"
#include "device_launch_parameters.h"


__global__ void add_arrays(int* A, int* B, int* C)
{
    C[threadIdx.x] = A[threadIdx.x] + B[threadIdx.x];
}

__global__ void index_initialize(int* data)
{
    // set data at index to index
    data[threadIdx.x] = threadIdx.x;
}

void zero_initialize(int* data, int size)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        data[i] = 0;
    }
}

void print_array(int* data, int size)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        std::cout << data[i] << " ";

        if (i % 20 == 0 && i > 0) std::cout << '\n';
    }
}


int main()
{
    GpuTimer timer;

    // size
    int size = 100;

    // host arrays
    int* hostA = new int[size];
    int* hostB = new int[size];
    int* hostC = new int[size];

    // device arrays
    int* deviceA = new int[size];
    int* deviceB = new int[size];
    int* deviceC = new int[size];

    // zero out host
    zero_initialize(hostA, size);
    zero_initialize(hostB, size);
    zero_initialize(hostC, size);

    // set to index
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        hostB[i] = i;
    }

    // allocate size ints on device
    cudaMalloc(&deviceA, size * sizeof(int));
    cudaMalloc(&deviceB, size * sizeof(int));
    cudaMalloc(&deviceC, size * sizeof(int));

    cudaMemcpy(deviceA, hostA, size, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaMemcpy(deviceB, hostB, size, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

    // call kernel on one thread block of size
    //index_initialize<<<1, size>>> (device);

    // call add kernel
    add_arrays<<< 1, size >>> (deviceA, deviceB, deviceC);

    // synchronize
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();

    // copy device to host
    cudaMemcpy(hostC, deviceC, size, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

    // reset device
    cudaDeviceReset();

    // print out host
    print_array(hostC, size);

    // free memory
    cudaFree(deviceA);
    cudaFree(deviceB);
    cudaFree(deviceC);

}
```

Comment: `cudaMemcpy(host, device, size, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);` -- you are only copying back one quarter of the array. [SO] isn't a free trivial mistake spotting service, please don't treat it like one.

Comment: thank you, I realized what I was doing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`cudaMemcpy()`](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/group__CUDART__MEMORY.html#group__CUDART__MEMORY_1gc263dbe6574220cc776b45438fc351e8) takes the size *in bytes* of the variable and not the number of elements

```
cudaMemcpy(host, device, size, cudaMemcpyDevicetoHost)
```

was only copying the first 100 of 400 bytes allocated for 100 ints. The correct copy statement would be

```
cudaMemcpy(host, device, size * sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyDevicetoHost)
```